# How to make navigation of IdeaVim (the hjkl arrows) work in Datagrip tables

Tags: datagrip, ideavim

A well known plugin IdeaVim works in Pycharm and Webstorm but can not make it work in Datagrip table view. I want to navigate with hjkl but it makes text immediately be inserted into cell and overwrite cell content.
Is that normal? Possible to have hjkl to navigate in DataGrip tables? Or hjkl keys will only work in DataGrip console?

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice idea! This feature is not supported by IdeaVim, but you can create an issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM